# Shell Script Variable Scope

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

We have two shell scripts (A & B) running parallelly on the same Linux machine. Here is the code of script A

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_VAR=Hello
// Script Code run for 5-10 seconds
```

Here is script B

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_VAR=HI
// Script Code run for 5-10 seconds
```

What will be the scope for the MY_VAR variable, If both scripts are running parallelly?

For example, if we start script A, and while script A is running we start script B. Would change in MY_VAR value in script B change it for script A as well (wherever we are accessing it in script A)

Comment: Fortunately, a bash variable is bound to one process. Several bash processes have their own set of variables. Imagine the havoc you could do, if shells would **share** their variable? You could ruin any shell script, which is running at the moment, by fiddling around with the variables it uses.

Answer (score 3):

The scope of each variable is only within its corresponding script. In the case you described there is no leakage outside of the script. There is no interference between the scripts. Even if you `EXPORT` the variable, there is no effect.

Example:

```
==> test1.sh <==
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "${MY_VAR} in 1"
export MY_VAR=Hello

for i in `seq 1 10` ; do
    echo "${MY_VAR} in 1"
    sleep 5
done

==> test2.sh <==
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "${MY_VAR} in 2"
export MY_VAR=Hi

for i in `seq 1 10` ; do
    echo "${MY_VAR} in 2"
    sleep 5
done
```

Run the scripts:

```
./test1.sh & ; sleep 10; ./test2.sh &
 in 1
Hello in 1
Hello in 1
 in 2
Hi in 2
Hello in 1
Hi in 2
Hello in 1
Hi in 2
Hello in 1
Hi in 2
Hello in 1
Hi in 2
```

Comment: By leakage I mean a case when variable defined in one scope affects the variable with the same name in another scope. In the case you described, the variable in script A does not affect the variable with the same name in script B.